# Xamarin Forms WCF losing session

Tags: wcf, cookies, xamarin, xamarin.forms, basichttpbinding

I'm implementing WCF in my Xamarin Forms project, but everytime I try to access the WCF host a second time it lost the data from the first time.

Is there a way in Xamarin Forms to work with cookies over a BasicHttpBinding?
And if so how can I implement these cookies?

I have no experience with cookies.